# $\mathbb{T}^4/\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{T}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-topology, projective-space, projective-module, surgery-theory

I was stuck by reading this figure:

It looks that $\mathbb{T}^4/\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{T}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are somehow related.

Are there some easier explanations from math directly?

[image]

It is a figure 2 in this ref: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FJHEP07%282017%29088.pdf

Comment: Plucked out of context, this doesn't make much sense. Opening up the paper to look at it in context, I would have to read a lot more of the paper. Unless you can somehow bridge that gap, it's pretty impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I don't understand the bit about $T^4$. The involution on $T^2 = \Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is given as $x \mapsto -x$. This has exactly four fixed points, and you can show that the quotient is homeomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$; it has four singular 'orbifold' points. This quotient is often called the pillowcase in the mathematics literature.

Comment: It seems like the appearance of $T^4$ is just a glaring typo. There is at least no isometric involution of $T^4$ that fixes exactly 4 points.